# What alternatives exist for Zone Alarm?

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, firewall

I like having Zone Alarm to warn me when programs are trying to phone home / request for updates etc.

However, I feel its interface is a little clunky and was wondering if there are any alternatives out there?

I'm running Windows XP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Comodo Firewall](http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/firewall.php), it is free, has a 64 bit option and a training mode so you can set it up with your programs quickly and pain free.

Answer (score 2):

[Sunbelt Personal Firewall](http://www.sunbeltsoftware.com/home-home-office/sunbelt-personal-firewall/) and [Jetico Personal Firewall](http://www.jetico.com/firewall-jetico-personal-firewall/) are both very good and very configurable.  Although I find the Jetico documentation to be a bit lacking.

Comment: Sunbelt is gone: *After many years as leader in firewall protection, Sunbelt Personal Firewall is being discontinued.*